# How can I use, clear, and re-use div for jQuery status messages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an empty `div` I use for status messages once my jQuery script executed successfully. I have various jQuery / AJAX calls that use the same div for status messages, however after the first script and first successful population of the div, the div is not reusable anymore, meaning the success message of the second script is not displayed.

How can I populate and then clear a div content **in order for it to remain re-useable later?**

```js
// populate status div
$('#status').html(response);

// remove success message after 5 secs
setTimeout(function() {
$('#status').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
```

I tried various other jQuery ways to clear the content, but all have the same result.

- `$('#status').empty()`
- `$('#status').val('')`
- `$('#status').end()`

Comment: would the user who voted to close this post please explain why? There are no search results for this specific behaviour.

Comment: [`fadeOut`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) sets `display: none` on the element after animating the opacity. Your code isn't removing that when setting the next message. (And easy way is to set it to `display: block`.)

Comment: thank you, I was not aware of that, this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please read documentation on what these jQuery methods does.

`.empty()` - removes all child elements
`.val('')` - is intended to be used on input elements only
`.end()` - `End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state` - does nothing to content itself.

You do not need to clear any content, since `fadeOut` will hide element. What you want to do is fadeIn that element again and set new content to it

```js
// populate status div
setContent('Initial content');

// remove success message after 5 secs
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#status').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000);

// show success message again after 10 secs
setTimeout(function() {
    setContent('Repeated content');
}, 10000);

function setContent(content) {
  $('#status')
      .html(content)
      .fadeIn('fast');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
```